# How to compare hashes of files in bash script?

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting, hashsum

I am using `sha256sum` to check whether file has changed or not within the bash script. My idea is to first store the `sha256sum` in a `*.sha256` file. Then if this is present then use this for `sha256` comparison using `--check` command. If hashes match then continue the rest of script otherwise create new hash file (`*.sha256`) and replace the older one with new hash file. I have done:

```
x="/home/test.json"

if [[ -s $x.sha256 ]]; then
        sha256sum --check $x.sha256
        #exit 1
        s1=$(sha256sum "$x" > "$x.sha256")
        #exit 1
else
        s1=$(sha256sum "$x" > "$x.sha256")
        echo "sha256 file is created"
fi
```

But from above code initially if x.sha256 file is not present, then it is created. But if file is already available and hashes doesn't match then it throws error:

```
/home/test.json: FAILED
sha256sum: WARNING: 1 computed checksum did NOT match
```

This is expected but in this case I want to create new `x.sha256` file and replace old file.

Can anyone please let me know what changes is needed?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sounds a bit like [Tripwire](https://github.com/Tripwire/tripwire-open-source/wiki)?

Comment: `s1=$(sha256sum "$x" > "$x.sha256")` should be `sha256sum "$x" > "$x.sha256"`

Comment: Hello @roaima, I made the above change. But, this didn't help. I still have same behavior.

Comment: TBH I'm not entirely clear what you think the problem is

Comment: You're running `sha256sum` on `"$x"` regardless of if the check fails so it looks like it should update the `.sha256` file after giving the warning. The command substitution in `s1=$(sha256sum "$x" > "$x.sha256")` is a bit useless, though, as you're redirecting the output of `sha256sum` to a file, there's no output for the shell to catch. It shouldn't affect what the program does, however. Also, it doesn't look like you're using `s1`. If you are, and want to get the output of `sha256sum` to a file and to a shell variable, then use something like `s1=$(sha256sum "$x" | tee "$x.sha256")`

Comment: Hello @ilkkachu, thats correct. I want to update `.sha256` file if the check fails. Right now it's not happening. It just exists after warning. What should I change here?

Comment: Is that your whole script? Are you by any chance using `set -e` (or running the script with `sh -e` or `bash -e` or such)?

Comment: Hello @ilkkachu, no this is just part of the script. BUt the script uses `set -Eeo pipefail`. So I think this is causing script to stop if there is an error, Right? Can I use something like `set +e` inside above `if` clause to continue execution if check fails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comment:

> But the script uses `set -Eeo pipefail`

`set -e` causes the whole script to fail if and when `sha256sum --check` exits with a falsy status. To avoid that, put the command in any sort of conditional, e.g. run `sha256sum --check || true instead`.

Also, as mentioned, `s1=$(sha256sum "$x" > "$x.sha256")` looks a bit off, as the output from `sha256sum` is redirected to a file, there's nothing for the command substitution to catch, and `$s1` ends up empty regardless of what happens. If you don't need `s1`, just drop the command substitution, and if you want to put the output of `sha256sum` in both the variable and the file, use something like

```
s1=$(sha256sum "$x" | tee "$x.sha256")
```

So, I'd rewrite the whole script as something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e
file="/home/test.json"

if [[ -s $file.sha256 ]]; then
    if ! sha256sum --check "$file.sha256"; then
        echo "stored hash for '$file' does not match existing file, storing new hash"
        sha256sum "$file" > "$file.sha256"
    else
        : # hash file exists and matches existing file, do nothing
    fi
else
    echo "no stored hash for '$file', creating hash file"
    sha256sum "$file" > "$file.sha256"
fi
```

That is, unless you need a copy of the hash further in the file, in which case the branch for an existing matching hash also needs to read `"$file.sha256"` in.

But if you're using `set -e`, see [BashFAQ/105 -- Why doesn't set -e (or set -o errexit, or trap ERR) do what I expected?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105)